# How to count the amount of words which have only a specific word as a suffix and only as a suffix?

Tags: c

So I have this and I want to:

```
For the word "are":

caramare
aresdn
lasrare
aresare
mare
```

`We have n=3` as only 3 words end in our specific word and have it inside only once.
If I read a wrong word, like "ares", `it will break the program.` Why is that?
It is required to start the program from:

```
n=.....;
for(i=1;i<=11;i++)
{ cin>>s; | scanf(“%s”,s);
 ............
}
```

This is what I have tried:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
int main()
{
    char s[20][20];
    int n=0;
    int i;
    for(i=1;i<=11;i++)
    {
        scanf("%s",s);
        if(strcmp ( strstr("are",s[i]) ,"are") ==0 )
        {
            n++;
        }

    }
    printf("%d",n);
}
```

Comment: What do you mean by "break the program"? I ran the code, and it ran fine, aside from the logic being wrong.

Comment: `scanf` `%s` is required? This is a bad exercise.

Comment: yeah, that's what the exercise requires

Comment: `char s[20][20];` is a real bad match for `scanf("%s",s);` ... and `scanf("%s",s);` is a sin anyway

Comment: can you tell me where I did wrong in my logic pls?

Comment: Yeah well, I started from the required block of code and I don't know to do else than that

Comment: @AndreiJarca You have not told which input that causes a failure...

Comment: The first problem is `char s[20][20];`. That's the wrong type.

Comment: By the way, can you please explain to me why scanf("%s",s); is very bad and why it is a bad match? I'm pretty bad at these. Only if you want to

Comment: @4386427 I said in the text, if you put a word which does not end in "are" , it will return some error

Comment: @AndreiJarca "it will return some error" - what is the error?

Comment: maybe an implementation that resembles Boyer-Moore starting directly to the end of the string for larger suffixes?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One problem is that `strstr` returns NULL if the needle is not found. Then you pass a NULL pointer to `strcmp` which will go all wrong.

You need to split it like:

```
    char* tmp = strstr("are",s[i]);
    if (tmp)
    {
        if (strcmp ( tmp ,"are") ==0 )
        {
            n++;
        }
    }
```

And this

```
char s[20][20];
```

shall just be:

```
char s[20];
```

and please **never, never ever** do `scanf("%s",s);` Always - like in **always, allways, allways** - put a limit - like `scanf("%19s",s);` so that the user can't overflow your input buffer.

Comment: Oh ok, it worked with "s", not "s[i]" and I made a char s[20];

Comment: why is it required to put those separated?

Comment: I mean, what does the if(tmp) do? Why is that required

Comment: If you put s[i] it will put error invalid conversion, but it works with *s*

Comment: @AndreiJarca The `if (tmp)` makes sure that `tmp` is **not** NULL when calling `strcmp` It could also be written like `if (tmp != NULL)`

Comment: oh ok , thats like tmp != NULL, yeah, that makes a lot of sense, thanks a lot for all the help, it's very useful, you should usually go for gets(s); I suppose?

Comment: @AndreiJarca I strongly prefer `fgets` for reading user input. After that `sscanf` is very handy